Dot product for binomial polynomials
Working with polynomials it's possible to find coefficient by n-th power of variable as integral, considering product like
\begin{align} (f,g) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(e^{i\phi})g(e^{-i\phi})d\phi \end{align}
I'm interested, whether there is such a bracket, with respect to wich binomial polynomials \begin{align} {x(x-1)...(x-n+1)}/{n!} \end{align} form an orthonormal basis?
